# about BRO: how to intercept AMQP messages(RabbitMQ) in OpenStack

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack, bro, zeek

I've been doing some experiment with BRO in OpenStack, and first of all, i need to intercept all the RabbitMQ messages with BRO, but i'm not really familiar with this tool and I've followed the step of the following git blog
https://github.com/packetsled/bro_amqp_plugin 
and there is an error
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4vVP.png)

Do anyone know what's wrong with my step? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response, but that version of the plugin is quite old, and not maintained.  An updated version for Zeek (formally known as Bro) 3.x is available at `https://github.com/mixmodeai/bro_amqp_plugin`.  I'm working on updating to 4.x, but it is a background task.

Please post the full text of the command you used for configuration and make, as well as the output.